# Routing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i am little bit confused in routing of laravel-5.2 . I am facing one issue. I have two routes that are follows:-

```
Route::get('{businessname}',BusinessController@getBusiness) //first Route
Route::get('{username}','UsersController@getusername') //second route
```

So yo see that `{businessname}` and `{username}` is dynamic.
But when i try to access the url like:-

```
Localhost:8000/dummy-business-name // this route is going to this function that is right .... -> BusinessController@getBusiness
```

But when i try second route of username it is also going to getBusiness function

```
Localhost:8000/kanu-mahajan i want this function should be redirect to UsersController@getusername
```

I know the alternative of this thing we can define Route like that

```
Route::get('user/{username}','UsersController@getusername')
```

But i don't want to do it in this way. Please help me how to do above routing in laravel 5.2 .

Comment: Both routes are using a dynamic wildcard, how is it to know which one is a username or a business?

Comment: that's the question how can i do this ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because it is basically the same route, just a different parameter.

You can do what you suggested with `user/{username}` or you can send all parameters to the same function and handle it from there.

For example:

```
Route::get('{name}', function ($name) {
    // if name is username then do something
    // or if name is business then do something else
});
```

Comment: if business name or username both are same then what can i do ??

Comment: you could always seperate out your code to other functions, that is better practice

Comment: is there no alternative to do that thing with Route:grouping

Comment: If business name and username are both the same then think about it. It will be the same url. The only way to do it is to make those 2 urls unique in some way.

Comment: actually i am working on some big project that client don't want 
like user/{username} and buisness/{business name } they want whole website should contain one paramter after domain name

Comment: Then I would suggest you use one function with conditions as in my answer